# How head.next is changed in singly linkedlist

Tags: java, algorithm, oop, data-structures, linked-list

I have a big confusion in the simple singly linked list such as :
in java.

node class  :

```
public class node {

    public int data;
    public node next;

    public node(int data , node next) {
       this.data = data;
       this.next = next; 
    }
}
```

linked list class :

```
public linked list{

    public node first;
    public node last;

    public void add(int data){

        node x = new node(data,null);

        if( first == null ) { first= x; }
        else { last.next = x; }
        last = x;

    }
}
```

Here the big confusion , if the linked list is empty and I am trying to add new node for example : `add(1);`

The data of first node will be 1 and the next of first node will be null
and also the data of last node will be 1 and the next of last node will be null

Now if I added  a new node for example : `add(2);`

The data of last node will be 2 and the next of last node will be null
and the data of first node will still 1 but the next of first node will be the tail, how this is happening ?

How head.next is changed in singly linkedlist ?

Comment: I believe your confusion will be cleared after understand how pointer works.

Comment: indeed , the problem is solved .
thank you

Comment: if that's what you're looking for, you may mark as "the answer". :) Welcome to SO.

Comment: for sure , i am sorry .
i am new member in stacoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how head.next is changed in singly linkedlist ?

**Short answer**: Because initially both `first` and `last` are pointing to the same node, `last.next = x` indirectly causes `first.next = x`.

---

**Long answer**:

The heart of it is object reference (pointer).

To understand why it changed, first you have to understand how pointer works in Java, a very high level language where you are hidden from all the nasty yet tedious memory manipulations.

### tldr; I would refer you to watch this epic video that talks about pointer, [Binky Pointer Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f-pJlnpkLp0).

---

#### How Pointer works in Java

**1. Memory allocation:**

Statement below allocates new memories to hold node values(data & next). `x` is now holding the address value, i.e: `0x1ACD` to actual node value. In other word, `x` is a node pointer.

```
  node x = new node(data,null); //0x1ACD
```

**2. Pointer Dereferencing:**

In order to access the actual node values, we need to dereference the address value. Pointer dereferencing happens when you access properties in Object, i.e: `node.Next`. The following statement dereference `last` and the object assignment copies the address value in `x` to `next`(property in `last`).

```
  last.next = x;
```

**3. Object assignments:**

Due to internal Java design (memory efficiency), instead of cloning the entire node value(in real world, it could be huge), object assignments copy only address value.

`first` and `last` now holds the same address value as `x`, which is address to actual node values.

```
public void add(int data){
    ...
    first = x; 
    last = x;
    ...
}
```

You may ask what is so great about this? Well, take the following example:

```
public void add(int data){
    ...
    first = x; 
    last = x;
    last.next = new node(123,null);
    ...
}
```

Note that now, `last.next == first.next`. Changing of node value via `last` also appears to modify `first`, because both of them are pointing to the same node values.

This is the complete answer to **how head.next is changed in singly linkedlist ?**

**References:**

1. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/207196/do-pointers-really-exist-in-java
2. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141834/how-is-a-java-reference-different-from-a-c-pointer

---

#### Illustrations:

**Step 1**: When we `add(1)` to an empty list:

```
public void add(int data) {
    ...
    first= x; 
    ...
    last = x;
    ...
} 

// after:
   [1] <- first, last           // first and last now pointing to the same `node:x`.  
    |
   [/] <- first.next, last.next // first.next, last.next pointing to null.
```

**Step 2**: Now, when we `add(2)` to the previous list(non-empty):

```
// before:
   [1] <- first, last          
    |
   [/] <- first.next, last.next // first.next, last.next pointing to null.

public void add(int data) {
    ...
    // technically, since first and last pointing to the same node[1],
    // x actually being assigned to both first.next and last.next.
    last.next= x; 
    ...
    last = x;     // update last from previous-x to current-x.
    ...
} 

// after:
   [1] <- first
    |
   [2] <- last      // first.next, last is pointing to the new `node:x`.
    |
   [/] <- last.next // last.next to null.
```

**Step 3 and etc**: Now, let's `add(3)` or subsequent values to the list(non-empty):

```
// before:
   [1] <- first
    |
   [2] <- last      
    |
   [/] <- last.next // last.next to null.

public void add(int data) {
    ...
    last.next= x; // access previous-x and assign x to previous-x's next.
    ...
    last = x;     // update last from previous-x to current-x.
    ...
} 

// after:
   [1] <- first
    |
   [2]         
    |
   [3] <- last      // last is pointing to the new `node:x`. 
    |
   [/] <- last.next // last.next to null.
```

---

#### Note:

- `first` always pointing to first node in list.
- `last` always pointing to last node in list.
- `last.next` is always pointing to null. Via `Add()`, a new node is always appended to the end of the list via assignment to `last.next`.

Comment: in the third step when we added 3 , first.next will be last . how this is happening ?
this is my point .